# Conversion issue when using Substring in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, substring

I am trying to update column values with other column values in the same data table based on some conditions(checks if the field has .pdf at the end). While updating the column values, I have to remove .pdf and then assign hence using SUBSTRING() for the same.

```
Update Table_name
Set col_1 = SUBSTRING(col_2, 1, LEN(col_2 - 4))
Where col_2 like '%.pdf%'
```

But I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting nvarchar value default.pdf to datatype int

Note : `col_1` and `col_2` both are of type `nvarchar(255)`

Comment: I tried CONVERT and CAST over SUBSTRING() but same issue

Comment: Why do you search for ".pdf" ANYWHERE within the column. Your logic is based on the assumption that the string ENDS with .pdf, so make your statement consistent! THINK! You should have `where col_2 like N'%.pdf';` Is your column nvarchar? Then use a unicode literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error with your LEN calculation. `LEN(col_2) - 4)` instead of `LEN(col_2 - 4)`:

SQL is trying to convert col_2 to an INT to first calculate col_2 - 4 before applying the LEN function. First, get the LEN(col_2) which returns an INT and then subtract 2.

**Solution:**

```sql
UPDATE Table_name
   SET col_1 = SUBSTRING(col_2, 1, LEN(col_2) - 4)
 WHERE col_2 LIKE '%.pdf%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your code has a minor syntax error. It should be

`SUBSTRING(col_2, 1, LEN(col_2) - 4)` the value of the column to be updated.

You can try this also using `charindex()` and `Reverse()` function as shown below.

```
create table MyTable
(
  col_1 nvarchar(255)
  , col_2 nvarchar(255)
)

insert into MyTable values
(null, 'ABC.pdf'),(null, 'MNO.pdf'),(null, 'PQR.pdf')

select * from MyTable

UPDATE MyTable
SET col_1 = left([col_2], len([col_2]) - charindex('.', Reverse([col_2])))
WHERE col_2 LIKE '%.pdf%'

select * from MyTable
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=841887d92810d0a4946b914452adb8c3) demo.